# dblatex ignore --texstyle or -s command

Tags: coding-style, docbook, asciidoc, dblatex

I want to write an asciidoc document and convert it into a pdf document. However, I want to use a format style different than the default ones. To do so I convert the txt file to docbook using asciidoc and then try to convert the resulting docbook xml to a pdf file using dblatex.
The idea is to set a particular tex style for dblatex to obtain the desired pdf result. I've copied the existing docbook.sty style as it is recommended [here](http://dblatex.sourceforge.net/doc/sec-custom-latex.html) to do a small style modification. The only change done in the ./docbook file is \setlength{\textwidth}{18cm} to \setlength{\textwidth}{12cm}. However, when I run the command

```
dblatex --texstyle=./docbook.sty test.txt
```

Or the command

```
dblatex -s ./docbook.sty test.txt
```

Both produce the same result in the style change: none. I mean, no matter which modification I do to ./docbook.sty file, these modifications are not applied to the output. I obtain always the same result, a pdf with the default formatting. Do you guys have any idea where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

- Copy the Dblatex docbook.sty to a new filename in your working directory which is "obviously yours" (e.g., mydbstyle.sty).
- Continue to supply a full or relative path argument to the --texstyle option (e.g., /path/to/mydbstyle.sty or ./mydbstyle.sty). Failing to do so requires that mydbstyle.sty be in a directory enumerated by the TEXINPUTS environment variable (which you likely have not explicitly set).
- Within mydbstyle.sty, use the following directives to initialize your style:

  ```
  \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
  \ProvidesPackage{mydbstyle}[2013/02/15 DocBook Style]
  \RequirePackageWithOptions{docbook}
  % ...
  % your LaTeX commands here
  ```
- Pass a DocBook 4.5 XML file as an argument to Dblatex (in your example you are passing test.txt which makes me uncertain whether you're passing an AsciiDoc source file).

  ```
  dblatex --texstyle=./mydbstyle.sty mybook.xml
  ```